# What is the reasoning behind the algorithm in the paper "An Image Signature for any kind of Image"?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, visual-studio-2012, image-processing, computer-vision

What is the reasoning behind the steps of the algorithms mentioned in the paper "An Image Signature for any kind of image" by H.Chi Wong, Marshall Bern, David Goldberg? 
This is the link to the research paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.2585&rep=rep1&type=pdf

The second step of the paper states that "For each column of the image we computer the sum of absolute values of differences between adjacent pixels in that column. We compute the total of all columns and crop the image at the 5%  and 95% columns, that is the columns such that 5%  of the total sum of differences lies on either side of the cropped image. " What do you mean by "cropping the image at the 5%  and 95% columns" and "lies on either side of the cropped image"? 
The first step is to convert the image to grayscale.

The second step states that a 9x9 grid of points must be imposed on the image, How is it possible to do so using OpenCV 2.4.11 in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

P.S: I am a student working for a non-profit cause in a research institute. Your answers to these questions will be very important and useful to implement a project to find similar images.

Comment: Regarding cropping at 5% and 95%: The first part of the second step ("For each column ...") computes a single number for each column.  If you add all these numbers together you get a total, t.  Now start from the leftmost column, building up a second sum as you move rightwards -- when this sum reaches t*0.05, stop.  Now do the same again, but this time starting from the rightmost column and moving leftwards.

Comment: Thanks j_random_hacker

Comment: You're welcome!  BTW, don't forget to put a "@" in front of a user's name in a comment if you want them to be notified.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement a project to find similar images, you don't need to re-code that, since there is a complete, working open source implementation (In Python) of the algorithm available here:

https://github.com/ascribe/image-match

This github repo claims to be an implementation of the mentioned paper: "An Image Signature for any kind of image" by H.Chi Wong, Marshall Bern, David Goldberg".